# Deactivate Checkbox in QT Designer

Tags: python, qt, checkbox, radio-button

I have a (very rough) GUI created using QT Designer.

Within it there are two radio buttons. When Button A is toggled I would like the check boxes below to be unavailable for use. 
When A is toggled, I would like to activate them.
Is this possible?

I have tried using the signal and slots mode, but I can only find an option to setChecked when B is toggled, not deactivate when A is toggled

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple: just connect radio button signal `toggled()` with group box's `setVisible()` slot.
This will completely hide the checkboxes.

You can also connect `toggled()` with every checkbox's `setDisabled()` slot just to deactivate them.

Comment: Ideal, I didn't have the 'Show signals and slots inherited from QWidget' selected before. Thanks alot